# Switching values in HTML boxes with values from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm just starting a programming class and I was assigned several assignments by my professor(he seems pretty lazy, just gives us assignments and we hand them back), and I'm stumped on some of them.

The first problem is to enter two values in two boxes and when a button is pressed, the two contents switch places. I got this far before stumping

```
<hmtl>
<body>
<script>
  a = document.getElementById("boxone");
  b = document.getElementById("boxtwo");

  i=a
  a=b
  document.write(i);
  document.write(a);
<script>

<input type="text" name="boxone" value=""><br>
<input type="text" name="boxtwo" value=""><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">


</body>
</html>
```

I know that the formula is wrong since it doesn't work and I think I may have done the HTMl wrong aswell.

I also have another problem where there are two boxes and I need to enter a Fahrenheit degree and once I click out the Celsius amount should show up in the other.

If anyone knows how to solve these please reply.Thank you

Comment: Your first error is `<hmtl>` :p

Comment: _he seems pretty lazy, just gives us assignments and we hand them back_. Isn't that how it always works? I suggest a course in HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: @putvande Usually there are some lectures  mixed in.

Comment: Go talk to your professor between classes, get him talking about a CS topic that really interests him. You will find that we are all in this together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `value` property to get or set the value of a box. You also need to put your code in a function, so you can attach it as a click handler to the button.

And you need to use `id` in the `<input>` elements, not `<name>` (the latter is only needed when submitting a form).

```
<script>
function switchValues() {
    a = document.getElementById('boxone').value;
    b = document.getElementById('boxtwo').value;

    document.getElementById('boxone').value = b;
    document.getElementById('boxtwo').value = a;
}
</script>

<input type="text" id="boxone" value=""><br>
<input type="text" id="boxtwo" value=""><br>
<input type="submit" onclick="switchValues()">
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/96Hrk/1/)

Comment: And OPs input fields don't have IDs, instead they have names.

Comment: Was just about to fix that, I noticed it when creating a fiddle.